# pandas dataframe merge with columns dayofweek and time as keys

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I want to merge this 2 Dataframes with '`dayofweek`' and '`time`' as keys

**df1** :

```
 nbcalls      nberrors  dayofweek        date      time
30857.142857  24267.714286          1  2021-10-26  11:00:00
32333.333333  25101.166667          1  2021-10-26  12:00:00
33333.333333  27336.500000          1  2021-10-26  13:00:00
34883.000000  27111.166667          1  2021-10-26  14:00:00
33120.833333  26644.666667          1  2021-10-26  15:00:00
...                           ...           ...        ...         ...       ...
5879.416667   4429.083333          1  2021-11-02  10:00:00
4902.250000   3685.583333          1  2021-11-02  11:00:00
5458.333333   4060.250000          1  2021-11-02  12:00:00
8358.333333   6611.916667          1  2021-11-02  13:00:00
6650.000000   4975.750000          1  2021-11-02  14:00:00
```

**df2** :

```
dayofweek      time  nbcalls  nberrors
0  00:00:00    16259.0     11396.0
0  01:00:00    20671.0     15442.0
0  02:00:00    28818.0     23304.0
0  03:00:00    32097.0     28012.5
0  04:00:00    25960.0     23998.0
..         ...       ...        ...         ...
6  19:00:00    45920.0     39319.5
6  20:00:00    28630.0     23379.0
6  21:00:00    29621.5     23090.0
6  22:00:00    26647.5     20969.5
6  23:00:00    21071.0     15068.0
```

I tried to do :

```
df_merge = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['dayofweek', 'time'], how='left', indicator=True)
```

The result is :

```
nbcalls      nberrors  dayofweek        date      time  nbcalls_y  nberrors_y     _merge
0    30857.142857  24267.714286          1  2021-10-26  11:00:00        NaN         NaN  left_only
1    32333.333333  25101.166667          1  2021-10-26  12:00:00        NaN         NaN  left_only
2    33333.333333  27336.500000          1  2021-10-26  13:00:00        NaN         NaN  left_only
3    34883.000000  27111.166667          1  2021-10-26  14:00:00        NaN         NaN  left_only
4    33120.833333  26644.666667          1  2021-10-26  15:00:00        NaN         NaN  left_only
..            ...           ...        ...         ...       ...        ...         ...        ...
167   5879.416667   4429.083333          1  2021-11-02  10:00:00        NaN         NaN  left_only
168   4902.250000   3685.583333          1  2021-11-02  11:00:00        NaN         NaN  left_only
169   5458.333333   4060.250000          1  2021-11-02  12:00:00        NaN         NaN  left_only
170   8358.333333   6611.916667          1  2021-11-02  13:00:00        NaN         NaN  left_only
171   6650.000000   4975.750000          1  2021-11-02  14:00:00        NaN         NaN  left_only
```

`nbcalls` and `nberrors` of `df2` columns are all to NaN what's wrong ?

Thanks for the help

Comment: Try `how='outer'`.

Comment: Not an 'outer' join